# Performance improvement in scroll-linked animations

Tags: javascript

I've created some effects in JavaScript (and with simple, CSS controlled animations), and they are working well, but costs a lot of hardware resources (especially GPU), so on devices with less performance, the webpage appears laggy when scrolling. The interesting thing is that I opened some webpages also with a lot of scroll-linked animations on devices with weak performance, and the animations looks smooth and nice.

I searched for solutions with performance improvement in scroll-linked effects, but the only thing I found is server-side pre-rendering (make screenshots from the webpage, and this way the page appears in one gif/video which frames are controlled depending on scroll). I was consider that it's possible to the root of the problem is that I don't use frameworks (JQuery, CSS preprocessors), but it can't be the only reason for this amount of performance cost. I tried to play with will-change in CSS, which make the effects smoother, but not enough.

An example of the effects I've created:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    var element = document.querySelector(.exampleElement),
      elementsContainer = element.parentNode,
      effect = (element.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset) / window.innerHeight;
    elementsContainer.style.perspective = "1000px";
    element.style.transform = "rotateX(" + effect * 90 + "deg)";
}
```

My question is that the only way to improve performance (to make the animations smooth on any devices) is the server-side rendering, or there are another way to do it? How other pages which uses scroll-linked animations make their effects smooth on any device?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious improvement is to move as much as possible outside of the scroll handler. Cause the handler is very vital for performance as it is triggered very often:

```
var element = document.querySelector(.exampleElement),
  elementsContainer = element.parentNode;

elementsContainer.style.perspective = "1000px";

window.onscroll = function() {       
   const effect = (element.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset) / window.innerHeight;
   element.style.transform = "rotateX(" + effect * 90 + "deg)";
}
```